# Java - JSoup log in InvestorsHub

Tags: java, jsoup

How do you login to InvestorsHub using Jsoup?

I tried the following with no success...

```
    res = Jsoup.connect("https://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/login.aspx").data("ctl00_CP1_LoginView1_Login1_UserName", "Myusername", "ctl00_CP1_LoginView1_Login1_Password", "Mypassword").method(Method.POST).execute();
    Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();
    doc = Jsoup.connect("link to the page").cookies(loginCookies).get();
```

Comment: Which line fails? Some exception or just nothing happens?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it helps first getting the the form itself before doing the post.

Try something like that (not tested):

```
    res = Jsoup.connect("https://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/login.aspx").get();

    res = Jsoup.connect("https://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/login.aspx").data("ctl00_CP1_LoginView1_Login1_UserName", "Myusername", "ctl00_CP1_LoginView1_Login1_Password", "Mypassword").method(Method.POST).cookies(res.cookies()).execute();
    Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();
    doc = Jsoup.connect("link to the page").cookies(loginCookies).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (**working solution**)

```
String loginURL = "https://investorshub.advfn.com/boards/login.aspx"

Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(loginURL)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

Document loginPage = response.parse();

Document document = Jsoup.connect(loginURL)
        .data("ctl00$CP1$LoginView1$Login1$UserName", "Myusername")
        .data("ctl00$CP1$LoginView1$Login1$Password", "Mypassword")
        .data("ctl00$CP1$LoginView1$Login1$LoginButton", "Log In")
        .data("__VIEWSTATE", loginPage.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
        .cookies(response.cookies())
        .post();
```